# GET_CONTENT intent works in debug, but not release build

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an issue with an intent I am running in my Android app. It works perfectly in the debug build of my app, but not in my release version. Am I missing something?

This is the intent code and activity result callback.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) return;
    if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
    mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(intent.getData());
    mUploadMessage = null;
}

private void pickFile() {
    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    chooserIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
}
```

Here I call the pickFile function

```
    echoView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String AcceptType, String capture) {
            this.openFileChooser(uploadMsg);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String AcceptType) {
            this.openFileChooser(uploadMsg);
        }

        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            pickFile();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE`? Is your `onActivityResult()` being called at all? What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @DavidWasser Yes, sorry for not being more elaborate. `openFileChooser` is not called at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found that there were two issues. One especially related to this issue regarding debug/release build, and one related to Android 4.4.

**Debug/release build**

Proguard was enabled for the release build, and appeared to strip a JavaScript interface, which for some reason interfered with the callback to `openFileChooser`.

**Android 4.4**

In KitKit, the Android team have removed the private API call to `openFileChooser` when the user tabs a `input[type=file]` element. I have yet to find a workaround. Until then file upload through a WebView seems impossible on 4.4.